# Navbar transition animation only on scroll up

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, css-transitions, transition

Currently, my navigation bar has a nice transition that makes it fade in when you scroll up. 
The issue that I am having is that when I scroll down, the transition animation does not apply, and it just vanishes without the fade.

This is the code for the transition:

```
transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
-webkit-transition: transform 500ms ease, background 500ms ease;
```

The class that the transition is applied to is `.main-menu`, however it is only triggering on the scroll up not the scroll down. I am not sure why this is happening since `.main-menu` is always present so should it not trigger regardless if the menu bar is displaying or not?

This is the link to the page: http://eg-graphics.com/Website%20New/about-us.html

Comment: It seems the position property on ".header_area". Change it to "fixed" from "absolute".

Comment: @MuraliNepalli this solution somewhat works, however when the navbar is disappearing, it starts being not directly touching the top of the page, and then slides up. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Worked it out, will post answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MuraliNepalli for the guidance with his comment. Thanks to that, I was able to work it out. The answer was as follows:

In the CSS I needed to set the following

```
.header_area {
  position: fixed; /* position needed to be fixed */
  width: 100%;
  top: -120px; /* top needed to be -120px */
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.header_area.navbar_fixed .main_menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: -120px; /* top needed to be -120px */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #000;
    transform: translateY(120px); /* translation needed to be -120px */
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
}
```